# How to extract value parsed from Eureka Forms?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, string, eureka-forms

I'm struggling to extract the exact value form a Eureka Form. Below is my source code thus far:

```
    class CommunityReportViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{

        @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
        var userTitleChoice: String = ""
        var userCategoryChoice : String = ""
        var userDescriptionChoice: String = ""



        @IBOutlet weak var submitReport: UIButton!



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            form +++ Section("Feedback Type")
                <<< SegmentedRow<String>("feedbackType"){
                    $0.options = ["Comments", "Bug Reports", "Questions"]
                    $0.value = "Comments"
                    }.onChange{ row in
                        let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                        userDefault.setValue(row.value, forKey: "feedbackType")
                }

                +++ Section("Follow up?")
                <<< ActionSheetRow<String>("officeLocation"){
                    $0.title = "Where are you?"
                    $0.selectorTitle = "Please select the office you are located in"
                    $0.options = ["Singapore", "Prague", "New Jersey"]

                }
                +++ Section("Best time to contact you?")

                <<< PopoverSelectorRow<String>("preferredMethod"){
                    $0.title = "Preferred Method"
                    $0.options = ["Phone", "Email", "Do Not Contact"]

                }
                <<< DateRow("preferredDate"){
                    $0.title = "Preferred date"

                }
                <<< TimeInlineRow("preferredTime"){
                    $0.title = "Preferred time"
                    $0.noValueDisplayText = "-:--"

                }




                <<< ButtonRow() {
                $0.title = "Submit Feedback!"
                $0.onCellSelection(self.buttonTapped)
                }



        }

    func buttonTapped(cell: ButtonCellOf<String>, row: ButtonRow) {
        let valuesDictionary = form.values(includeHidden:true)
        print (valuesDictionary["feedbackType"], "Feedback")
        print (valuesDictionary["officeLocation"], "Office")
        print (valuesDictionary["preferredTime"], "Time")
        print (valuesDictionary["preferredMethod"], "Method")
        print (valuesDictionary["preferredDate"], "Date")
}
}
```

The valuesDictionary returned result returned as below when no input is provided:

```
Optional(Optional("Comments")) Feedback
Optional(nil) Office
Optional(nil) Time
Optional(nil) Method
Optional(nil) Date
```

When correct inputs are provided , the following result is returned :

```
Optional(Optional("Comments")) Feedback
Optional(Optional("New Jersey")) Office
Optional(Optional(2016-07-08 10:00:23 +0000)) Time
Optional(Optional("Email")) Method
Optional(Optional(2016-07-11 07:00:16 +0000)) Date
```

Is there a way to returned only the values that is selected by the user? Because the returned results are difficult to parse.
Example I only want the following results returned

```
    Comments
    New Jersey
    Email
    2016-07-08 10:00:23 +0000
    2016-07-11 07:00:16 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can already get the values. All you have to do is check if the field has value and unwrap the optionals:

```
if let feedbackType = valuesDictionary["feedbackType"] as? String
{    
    print(feedbackType) //should print only "Comments"   
}
```

If the the value is nil it wouldn't satisfy the condition and skip the code inside the if block.

So basically when you print out the optional it looks like a convoluted string that needs to be parsed but they just need to be unwrapped to access the actual value.

You can find out more about optionals in Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Answer (score 0):

Must be extended to handle more type (int, ...)

```
let fvalues = form.values().mapValues { value -> String in
    return value as? String ?? ""
}
```